# Big O notation for matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, operator-theory

I am trying to understand the statement of the Riemann hypothesis (RH) in terms of the determinant of the Redheffer matrices $R_n$.

As outlined in [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis), the RH is equivalent to a bound on the growth of the determinant of these matrices as a function of $n$. Specifically, the RH is equivalent to the statement that $\operatorname{det}R_n = O(n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ for every positive $\epsilon$.

I take this to mean that for every positive $\epsilon$ there is a real number $A$ and an integer $n_0$ such that

$|\operatorname{det}R_n| \leq A|n^{\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon}|$ whenever $n \geq n_0$.

I do not know how such a bound can be shown to exist for any matrix - must it truly exist for *any* positive $\epsilon$? I suspect that a concrete, constructive example of a non-trivial infinite dimensional matrix with a similar bound would be very helpful. Any comments on relations between this and Hadamard’s maximal determinant problem would also be appreciated.

I am aware of the generalisation of the notion of a determinant to infinite dimensional vector spaces that occur in the Fredholm theory of trace class operators, but I am not sure how, if at all, this is related to my question.

Comment: Redheffer matrices defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redheffer_matrix)

Comment: Something that makes the "for every $\epsilon > 0$" behavior seem a little less strange: note that we can prove something similar for a function like $f(n) = \log(n)\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Can you expand on your comment?

Comment: so, in particular: for my $f(n)$ as defined above, we have $f(n) = O(n^{\frac 12 + \epsilon})$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, but $f(n)$ is not $O(n^{1/2})$.  To show that this is the case, it suffices to consider the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^p}
$$
and note that this limit is $0$ when $p > 1/2$ and $\infty$ when $p \leq 1/2$.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that is clear @Omnomnomnom :). I am still struggling to think of a non-trivial case where a bound can be found for the determinant of a matrix that can be of any order $n$ . This is my first post, and I would be happy to rephrase/post the question in another form if that is more likely to attract interest. What do you think?